# array based implementation of stack in C

Tags: c, arrays, stack

I'm referring to this source for array-based implementation of stacks.
Somewhere on the page, it says,

> Dynamically-sized stack: Now, we will add one more choice to how we'll
>   implement our stack. We want to be able to decide the maximum size of
>   the stack at run-time (not compile-time).
>
> Thus, we cannot use a regular array, but must use a pointer to a
>   dynamically-allocated array.
>
> Now, will we need to keep track of any more information besides the
>   contents and top?
>
> Answer: Yes! We'll need to keep the size of this array, i.e., the
>   maximum size of the stack. We'll see why this is necessary as we write
>   the code.

What does it mean to **decide the maximum size of the stack at run-time** , given the fact that **we need to keep the size of the array, i.e. max size** ? we still need the variable that stores the max size of the stack for dynamically allocating memory so I'm not quite sure how this would be beneficial as opposed to having a regular array and declaring capacity(max size) of it.

Comment: It basically means than rather than using `yourtype stack[MAX_STACK_SIZE]` you will use `int max_stack_size = <<some value>>; yourtype stack* = malloc(sizeof(yourtype)*max_stack_size);`. If you need more help, I'll make a proper answer but I think this might give you what you need.

Comment: @Aif if you think you're answering the question, then answer the question. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because using a dynamically allocated array, you may choose to expand it (allocate a larger array when needed) or to minimize it (free some memory to reduce RAM usage).

What you'd be probably referring to is [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/), [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) and [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/). What you'd want to do is to allocate some memory using `malloc` and keep its size in another variable.

When the stack is exhausted (i.e the amount of items in it is equal to its size) - you'd want to call `realloc` to "expand" the array, and update the stack's size.

Comment: Well, I do not disagree, but why would one do such a thing? All pointers into the stack might become invalid and you have to copy the whole contens on each realloc(). It that is an assignment (what I anticipate), it is just nonsense.

Comment: Why you want to keep pointers into the stack at all? You're unfamiliar with basic programming concepts (Google "SOLID"). The stack isn't meant for you to have pointers to, it is meant solely to allow for `pop` and `push` operations. Anything else is interference with the stack's implementation. What if you have implemented a stack using something else then an array and an index?

Comment: Yeah, believe it. Actually, every C-program which passes pointers to local variables e.g. to fscanf does it! You really should be careful who you blame of ignorance! You just have to ensure these pointers get out of scope not later than the referenced object. It also works very well for a list-based stack (which would actually be the better approach, as you do not have to copy the contents. Btw. you silently ignore that part of my comment. Intentionally? Don't think so...

Comment: @Olaf Was that a comment for me? If so, you didn't understand what I wrote. When I wrote "stack" I meant the stack that OP implements (using a `struct` to keep track of it or something) - not the stack pointed out by `esp` (or `rsp`). These two are quite different.

Comment: As a comment is always posted to the answer, too and I did not add another addressee, one could think so. And: he does not "use a struct ...", but an array of entries. He does not even mention it would be an array of struct. And: no, the hardware stack (btw: ARM for instance does not have ESP/RSP, but just SP) works exactly this way: an array of bytes (depending on the arch properly aligned) which is structured into: function arguments, return frame (address, possibly framepointer), local variables. The question can very well be for a CPU-emulator/simulator or a bytecode-intepreter.

Comment: If you refer to the hardware implementation as the difference: how about a VHDL implementation for an FPGA? "Look there's a green bird" "All birds are green!" "Look there's a red bird" " That can't be a bird; it's not green"

Comment: @Olaf Yes, `arm` CPUs have an `sp` register that stands for `Stack Pointer` and `x86` running in `real mode` have an `sp` register too, in `protected mode` they have `esp` that stands for `Extended Stack Pointer`... However, it is clear that OP doesn't address these implementations but rather is faced by an assignment to implement a stack in C ("Thus, we cannot use a regular array, but must use a pointer to a dynamically-allocated array." - CPUs don't "know" what is a "dynamically allocated array" ...)

Comment: You missed the second part of my post - again. Btw. There were very well CPU designs which actually were aware of data types. Read about the [iAPX432](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_iAPX_432) for example. And bytecode interpreters also just simulate a virtual CPU. They also have some knowledege on data types. Get the basics right first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78634/discussion-between-mark-segal-and-olaf).

Comment: Oh, and that about pointer into the stack: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) one does actually creates pointers into the stack.

Comment: @MarkSegal So "at run-time" essentially would mean that I keep a check to see if stack is full while pushing onto the array, and if full, I call realloc to expand memory ?

If I were to use a regular array, it is somehow inefficient to expand its size again.


This makes sense to me. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @Raaj Yes. Please note that you can't "expand a regular array" (unless you know the internals of your environment and compiler)

Comment: @Raaj: problem is that the memory not only changes its size, but also its location. Note that `realloc()` might fail as much as `malloc()`. **Always** check the results, otherwise you get _undefined behaviour_.